# Facebook app database issue: Store my own User ID or just use Facebook UID?

Tags: facebook

I want to create a Facebook app that can operates inside IFrame / FB connect.
I have to store some user information inside my database, but I still can't decide whether to use Facebook UID as the primary key or to create my own user ID (and have the Facebook UID as a regular column). Which approach is commonly used and why?

Thanks !
Andree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Facebook UID are also unique, as far as I am concerned, i always use the **Facebook UIDs**. Although that shouldn't a problem if you create your own ID but that would be an extra overhead.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. How do you store the Facebook UID in the database, by the way? Does it makes any difference if I store it as BIGINT (MySQL) instead of string, performance wise?

Comment: @Andree: Yes we use bigint, facebook ids are numbers and that is reasonable choice, also better as far as performance is concerned.